# Table in landscape mode keeps going out of bounds

Tags: tables, landscape

I can't figure out why my table keeps going out of bounds. It's like overleaf doesn't want to change the height of rows, it doesn't divide the content of a cell but keeps it in a line. Probably is something really stupid and I am overthinking.

here is my table

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more "open" look
\caption{Candidate DACs\label{tab:dac}}

    \begin{tabulary}{\paperheight}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Classe di servizi} & \textbf{Nome servizio} & \textbf{Modalità di fornitura} & \textbf{Remunerazione} \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{\textbf{Frequenza}} & Riserva inerziale & Automatico & Nessuna \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & Riserva primaria & Obbligatorio   per le unità abilitate & Nessuna \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & Riserva secondaria & \multirow{6}{*}{Tramite   MSD} & \multirow{6}{*}{Pay-as-bid   €/MWh} \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Riserva terziaria  pronta &  &  \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Riserva Terziaria rotante &  &  \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Riserva Terziaria   di sostituzione &  &  \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Bilanciamento &  &  \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{Gestione vincoli di rete} & Risoluzione  delle congestioni &  &  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Regolazione di tensione}} & Primaria & \multirow{2}{*}{Obbligatorio   per le unità abilitate} & \multirow{2}{*}{Nessuna} \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Secondaria &  &  \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Ulteriori servizi}} & Interrompibilità del  carico & Aste   dedicate per unità di carico & €/(MW*anno) + Pay-as-bid (€/MW) \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & Emergenza (rifiuto del carico) & Obbligatorio   per unità di produzione >100 MW & \multirow{2}{*}{Nessuna} \\ \cline{2-3}
 & Ripristino (Rialimentazione del sistema elettrico) & Obbligatorio   per UP rilevanti al fine del black start &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabulary} 

\end{sidewaystable}
```

Here's the picture, this is what I mean with "out of bounds"

[image]

Comment: you have used `c` columns which are always as wide as the text on one line, do not use those with `tabulary` use `C`  {or better `L` as centred text does not look good here}

Comment: `\paperheight` is too much that would force the table to over-print the page number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c` columns prevent `linebreaking`. You could use `tabulary` `L` columns, but I would not unless this is an automated workflow requiring automatic column width assignments. I would use a standard tabular.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more "open" look
\caption{Candidate DACs\label{tab:dac}}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|
 >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}|
 >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5.5cm}|
 >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|
 >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Classe di servizi} & \textbf{Nome servizio} & \textbf{Modalità di fornitura} & \textbf{Remunerazione} \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{=}{\textbf{Frequenza}} & Riserva inerziale & Automatico & Nessuna \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & Riserva primaria & Obbligatorio   per le unità abilitate & Nessuna \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & Riserva secondaria & \multirow{6}{=}{Tramite   MSD} & \multirow{6}{=}{Pay-as-bid   €/MWh} \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Riserva terziaria  pronta &  &  \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Riserva Terziaria rotante &  &  \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Riserva Terziaria   di sostituzione &  &  \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Bilanciamento &  &  \\ \cline{1-2}
\textbf{Gestione vincoli di rete} & Risoluzione  delle congestioni &  &  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\textbf{Regolazione di tensione}} & Primaria & \multirow{2}{=}{Obbligatorio   per le unità abilitate} & \multirow{2}{=}{Nessuna} \\ \cline{2-2}
 & Secondaria &  &  \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{=}{\textbf{Ulteriori servizi}} & Interrompibilità del  carico & Aste   dedicate per unità di carico & €/(MW=anno) + Pay-as-bid (€/MW) \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & Emergenza (rifiuto del carico) & Obbligatorio   per unità di produzione >100 MW & \multirow{2}{=}{Nessuna} \\ \cline{2-3}
 & Ripristino (Rialimentazione del sistema elettrico) & Obbligatorio   per UP rilevanti al fine del black start &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I'd also run `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble to render the text-mode `>` symbol properly.

Comment: @Mico oops;-) will fix (done)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that employs the machineries of the `tabularx` and `booktabs` packages. Note that I'd do away with all vertical rules -- they're just not needed, but do create needless visual clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,multirow,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X} % variable-width X-type columns

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Candidate DACs\strut} \label{tab:dac}

\begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{@{} >{\bfseries}l L{1} L{1.2} L{0.8} @{}}
\toprule
Classe di servizi 
  & \textbf{Nome servizio} 
  & \textbf{Modalità di fornitura} 
  & \textbf{Remunerazione} \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{10.5}{*}{Frequenza} 
 & Riserva inerziale  & Automatico & Nessuna \\ \cmidrule(l){2-4} 
 & Riserva primaria   & Obbligatorio per le unità abilitate & Nessuna \\ \cmidrule(l){2-4} 
 & Riserva secondaria & \multirow{7}{*}{Tramite MSD} & \multirow{7}{*}{Pay-as-bid €/MWh} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
 & Riserva terziaria pronta \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
 & Riserva Terziaria rotante \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
 & Riserva Terziaria di sostituzione \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
 & Bilanciamento \\ 
\midrule
Gestione vincoli di rete & Risoluzione delle congestioni \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Regolazione di tensione} 
  & Primaria 
    & \multirow{2.4}{*}{Obbligatorio per le unità abilitate} 
    & \multirow{2.4}{*}{Nessuna} \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
  & Secondaria\\ 
\midrule
\multirow{6.6}{*}{Ulteriori servizi} 
  & Interrompibilità del carico 
  & Aste dedicate per unità di carico 
  & €/(MW${}\cdot{}$anno) + \mbox{Pay-as-bid} (€/MW) \\ 
  \cmidrule(l){2-4} 
  & Emergenza (rifiuto del carico) 
  & Obbligatorio per unità di produzione >100 MW 
  & \multirow{4.4}{*}{Nessuna} \\ 
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
  & Ripristino (Rialimentazione del sistema elettrico) 
  & Obbligatorio per UP rilevanti al fine del black start \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: |+1|for|no|rules|